# CLDC & CDC in J2ME from Android point of view

Tags: java, android, java-me, cdc, cldc

Like the title says, I am wondering, there is a CDC and CLDC in J2ME, and I want to know what resembles them in the Java for Android point of view. Maybe something like comparisons, or what's in the CDC in J2ME and what Java for Android's elements best resembles it.

Answer (score 3):

Android doesn't really have an equivalent of CDC/CLDC.

Android is a much more monolithic development environment. There is *only* the Android SDK.

Granted, there are different levels of API support, but they are (until now) monotonously increasing and each level of support implies all previous ones as well.

In that respect the Android platform is much more like the Java SE platform: a single platform/API with different version, trying to be backwards compatible as much as possible.